# Javascript and HTML fill variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

so I'm trying to get a html radio button when pressed to send a value to the variable (UserInput) in the JavaScript code.

```
//HTML CODE// 
</HEAD>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/question.js"></script>
<BODY>

<form>

<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="Home" VALUE="1" >Home
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="School" VALUE="2" >School
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="Work" VALUE="3" >Work


<center><input type="button" name="send" value="Submit" onclick="var UserInput=getValue();"></center>
</form>


</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I would like to get the value from the radio buttons and store them in the variable UserInput,however it does not seem to be working.

```
// Javascript code (qustion.js) //

var UserInput = '';

if (UserInput=== '3')
{
   confirm("You have selected WORK");
   console.log("WORK");
}

else if (UserInput==='2')
{
    confirm("You have selected SCHOOL");
    console.log("SCHOOL");
}
else if (UserInput==='1') 
{
    confirm("You have selected HOME");
    console.log("HOME");
}
else if (UserInput==='')
{
    confirm("You have selected NOTHING");
    console.log("NONE");
}
```

Thanks,also I'm sort of a beginner so a in-depth explanation would be great too.

Comment: where is `getValue()` in your `question.js` ?

Comment: I though getValue() would get the value of the selected radio buttons,but I was not sure if that was right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first set the same name property to your radios for create a group

```
<INPUT TYPE="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="Home" VALUE="1" >Home
<INPUT TYPE="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="School" VALUE="2" >School
<INPUT TYPE="radio"  name="optionsRadios" id="Work" VALUE="3" >Work
```

after call the function on your button

```
<input type="button" name="send" value="Submit" onclick="getValue();">
```

and last create the function `getValue` and use :

```
document.querySelector("input[name=optionsRadios]:checked").value;
```

the querySelector return all the objects with the name "optionRadios" and checked , in this case just one

```
function getValue(){

var UserInput = '';
    UserInput= document.querySelector("input[name=optionsRadios]:checked").value;

if (UserInput=== '3')
{
   confirm("You have selected WORK");
   console.log("WORK");
}

else if (UserInput==='2')
{
    confirm("You have selected SCHOOL");
    console.log("SCHOOL");
}
else if (UserInput==='1') 
{
    confirm("You have selected HOME");
    console.log("HOME");
}
else if (UserInput==='')
{
    confirm("You have selected NOTHING");
    console.log("NONE");
}

}
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/RrYJu/1/

Answer (score 2):

first you have to use a single name for all, to make them a group (let's say here the group name is `myradiogroup`), you can define different ids, then do this:

```
document.querySelector('input[name=myradiogroup]:checked').value
```

you can also do this in your onclick event:

```
<input type="button" name="send" value="Submit"
    onclick="var UserInput=document.querySelector('input[name=myradiogroup]:checked').value;">
```

Comment: Sorry,but the document.querySelector,should that be put in the onClick="".

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this in the Html side:

```
</HEAD>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/question.js"></script>
<BODY>

<form>

<INPUT TYPE="radio" id="Home" VALUE="1"  >Home



<center><input type="button" name="send" value="Submit" onclick="var UserInput=getValue();"></center>
</form>
```

and the js side like this:

```
var UserChoice;
function getValue(){
if ($('input[id = Home]:checked').size() > 0) {
        UserChoice = "Home";
    }
}
```

Same is applicable to school and work

Answer (score 0):

```
var UserInput = '';
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:radio').click(function() {
       if ($(this).is(':checked'))
           {UserInput =$(this).val();}
       });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
        <script>
$(function(){
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
      alert($(this).val());
    }
  });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily accomplish this by using jquery

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
 $(function(){
    $(".button_classname_here").click(function(){       
        alert($('input[type=radio]:checked').val());
    });
});
</script>
```